# Magento 2 admin login redirects to login page issue

Tags: admin, login, admin-panel, admin-login

I cant seem to login into my magento 2 backend.
When I enter the correct credentials it just redirects me to the login page with no error.
Debug, system and exception log are clean.
Cache is cleaned already.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same issue. Solved it by **deleting my cookies**.

Comment: After deleting all the cookies in Chrome 61.0.3163.91 I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. This only happens in Chrome, Firefox works ok. Any idea why?

Comment: This is not proper solution to get clear browser cookie every time. Is there any permanent solution?

Answer (score 1):

This issue also shows up when there's an unknown bug in an extension that affects sales display (the dashboard shows sales data). In my case, I just ported an M1 module to M2 using the extremely helpful but seriously flawed Code Migration Toolkit (https://github.com/magento/code-migration). I then ran the command `php bin/magento module:enable My_Module` and restored my database (migrated from M1 to M2). I couldn't log in so I came across this Stack question and others like it telling me to clear cookies and remove rows from core_config_data. After 1 hour of head scratching, I realized it must be the last thing I did when admin login started to fail. It must be the module that I just enabled. So I disabled it and was able to log in.

Inspecting the code, I came across a configuration file etc/sales.xml that the CMT ported over from M1 to M2. This config file was trying to load a model using the old M1 class name `my_module/quote_discount` and failing. I commented this out and reenabled the module and was able to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

I just had same issue with Magento 2.3.1 after creating a clone site for testing.
in firefox chrome, cleared Cache in firefox and its working

i also clean/flush cache of magento from terminal, deployed static content. no fix
then cleared browser cache, Fixed issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I am also getting same issue but we have resolved it:
> For this command :

```
> php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 2560000
```

> And also update the core_config_data table:

```
> UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 7200 WHERE path = 'admin/security/session_lifetime';
> UPDATE core_config_data SET value = NULL WHERE (path = "web/cookie/cookie_domain" OR path = "web/cookie/cookie_path");
```

Resolved this above solution.
Thanks